# If we find a star exploding 100 light years away, that means it happened 100 years before?

Tags: spacetime, reference-frames, speed-of-light

So can someone please help me with this? Can someone make the answer as simple as possible?
So my question is if we see a star exploding like 100 light-years away, that means that star exploded 100 years in the past?

Answer (score 1):

It means the star exploded 100 years ago  *in our reference frame* . You need to bear in mind that the elapsed time from an event some distance away depends upon the frame of reference in which the time is measured.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you are absolutely right.

Since light travels with a finite speed $c=299792458\,\text{km/s}$, *everything* you see has happened in the past. As $v=s/t$, if you see something at a distance $s$, you actually see it as it was $t=s/c$ ago.

For everyday situations, this delay is unperceivable and it's only really relevant on astronomical scales. If you have the distance to something given in x lightyears/days etc., you can just remove the "light" to know that the image of the object you see is what the object looked like x years/days etc. ago.